# Using jq to fetch key value from json output

Tags: linux, bash, shell, curl, jq

I have a file that looks as below:

```
{
  "repositories": [
   {
    "id": "156c48fc-f208-43e8-a631-4d12deb89fa4",
    "namespace": "rhel12",
    "namespaceType": "organization",
    "name": "rhel6.6",
    "shortDescription": "",
    "visibility": "public"
   },
   {
    "id": "f359b5d2-cb3a-4bb3-8aff-d879d51f1a04",
    "namespace": "rhel12",
    "namespaceType": "organization",
    "name": "rhel7",
    "shortDescription": "",
    "visibility": "public"
   }
  ]
 }
```

I want to get only name values with each of them in a new line so that I can use `while read -r line`.
I need only

```
rhel6.6 
rhel7
```

I am using jq as follows which doesn't seem to work:

```
jq -r '.[].name'
```

Please suggest correct use of jq here

Answer (score 109, accepted):

You need to combine filters by means of `|` operator:

```
$ jq -r '.[] | .[] | .name' test.json 
rhel6.6
rhel7
```

The first `.[]` fetches `repositories` array. The next `.[]` fetches all the items of the `repositories` array. Finally, `.name` extracts properties from the array items(objects).

Note, the first `.[]` works on object because it is a documented feature:

```
.[]
    If you use the .[index] syntax, but omit the index entirely, it
    will return all of the elements of an array...

    You can also use this on an object, and it will return all the
    values of the object.
```

Comment: thanks for your response. Can you please how can i get output in format `rhel12/rhel6.6`  In other words, I need o/p in format `namespace/name`

Comment: @meallhour, `jq  -r '.[] | .[] | [.namespace, .name] | join("/")' test.json`

Answer (score 37):

You want to look at the repositories array instead of treating the input as an array:

```
$ jq -r '.repositories[].name' file
rhel6.6
rhel7
```

Answer (score 17):

Here is another solution.  Assuming the requirements

> I want to get only name values with each of them in a new line so that I can use while read -r line.
>
> Can you please how can i get output in format rhel12/rhel6.6 In other words, I need o/p in format namespace/name

if the data is in `data.json` then the command

```
jq -M -r '.repositories[] | "\(.namespace)/\(.name)"' data.json
```

should produce

```
rhel12/rhel6.6
rhel12/rhel7
```