# Ansible: debug only output from tasks?

Tags: ansible

When I use like `ansible-playbook -vvvv`, it shows all `stdout` for all running tasks. Though what it also shows, is noise that shows how each command is run through SSH.

Is there a way to use verbosity to just show tasks stdout without any other noise?

Currently it shows output like this:

```yaml
<myhost> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: root
<myhost> SSH: EXEC ssh -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=30m -o PreferredAuthentications=publickey -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="root"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/tmp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r myhost '/bin/sh -c '"'"'rm -f -r /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1333333.89364-1154635-13434444/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'"'"''
<myhost> (0, b'', b'OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.4, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files\r\ndebug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *\r\ndebug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master\r\ndebug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug2: mux_client_hello_exchange: master version 4\r\ndebug3: mux_client_forwards: request forwardings: 0 local, 0 remote\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session: entering\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_alive: entering\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_alive: done pid = 1136353\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session: session request sent\r\ndebug3: mux_client_read_packet: read header failed: Broken pipe\r\ndebug2: Received exit status from master 0\r\n')
changed: [dev] => {
    "changed": true,
    "cmd": [
        "/opt/odoo/.local/bin/docker-compose",
        "rm",
        "-fsv",
        "odoo"
    ],
    "delta": "0:00:03.287055",
    "end": "2022-01-25 08:09:25.105235",
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "_raw_params": "/opt/odoo/.local/bin/docker-compose rm -fsv odoo",
            "_uses_shell": false,
            "argv": null,
            "chdir": "/opt/odoo/app",
            "creates": null,
            "executable": null,
            "removes": null,
            "stdin": null,
            "stdin_add_newline": true,
            "strip_empty_ends": true,
            "warn": false
        }
    },
    "msg": "",
    "rc": 0,
    "start": "2022-01-25 08:09:21.818180",
    "stderr": "Stopping app_odoo_1 ... \r\nStopping app_odoo_1 ... done\r\nRemoving app_odoo_1 ... \r\nRemoving app_odoo_1 ... done",
    "stderr_lines": [
        "Stopping app_odoo_1 ... ",
        "Stopping app_odoo_1 ... done",
        "Removing app_odoo_1 ... ",
        "Removing app_odoo_1 ... done"
    ],
    "stdout": "Going to remove app_odoo_1",
    "stdout_lines": [
        "Going to remove app_odoo_1"
    ]
}
```

Is there a way to just keep `JSON` part without explicitly specifying `debug` arg for each task?

Answer (score 0):

When using [Ansible in Verbose Mode](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/cli/ansible-playbook.html#cmdoption-ansible-playbook-v) like `ansible-playbook -vvvv`, it shows how each command is run through SSH and it **also** shows all `stdout` for all running tasks.

> *verbose mode (-vvv for more, -vvvv to enable connection debugging)*

This is so far the intended behavior.

> *Is there a way to use verbosity to just show tasks `stdout` without any other noise?*

Even the parameters `-v` or `-vv` producing a kind of noise. This is also the intended behavior since the feature is for debugging functionality outside of tasks. See in example [source query `vvv`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/search?q=vvv)  or [source query `verbose`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/search?&q=verbose).

> *Is there a way to just keep JSON part without explicitly specifying `debug` arg for each task?*

I am not aware of any feature like that.

Currently I assume it would be necessary to use the [`debug`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/debug_module.html)_module. Or using the [Playbook Debugger to Debugging tasks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_debugger.html). With that it would be possible to get the `stdout` of a task only.

**Further Readings**

- [How to debug Ansible issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42417079/)
- [Debugging modules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/debugging.html)

---

Aside from Ansible there might be a way of filtering the output in example via `| grep -A2 stdout` or `awk 'p; / =>/ {p=1}'`, `sed '0,/ => /d'` and than `| jq -M -r '.stdout'`, respective `| jq -M -r '.stdout_lines'`.

**Thanks to**

- [Delete everything before pattern including pattern using `awk` or `sed`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19047312/)
- [Using `jq` to fetch key value from JSON output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39798542/)